# In Drools, does memberOf / contains require the tested object to be inserted as fact explicitly?

Tags: drools

I am still trying to wrap my head around some basics of drools.
One thing I don't understand is to what level I have to explicitly add facts into a session vs. declaring something as a fact or (how is it different?) as a variable within a rule.

Question: Do I always have to explicitly add a fact or does drools see a declared variable somehow as a fact as well?

Say I have this simplified hiearchy:

```
public class Container {
    private Collection<Element> elements;
    // other stuff
}

public class Element {
    private SubElement subElement;
    // other stuff  
}

public class SubElement {
    private code;
    // other stuff
}
```

Now I want to find/match a container that contains Elements with a SubElement of a given code.
This is a rule I created:

```
global Collection qualifyingCodes;
rule "container rule"
when
    // find a container 
    $container : Container( $elements : elements )

    // where there is an element within its elements list
    $element : Element(this memberOf $elements)

    // that has a sub element
    $subElement : SubElement(this == $element.subElement)

    // for which the code is in the (global) list of codes
    eval(qualifyingCodes.contains($subElement.code)) 
then
    ....
```

Now it seems to work fine, but only if I add the container, the elements and subelements separately as facts into my session.
I was hoping to be able to just add the container object as a fact and due to the "declared" $elements/$element/$subElement drools would understand those as facts as well. 
Is there a way to do this (or do I always have to flatten out my data structures and add those as separate facts)?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POJOs inserted as facts can be matched with a pattern without the need for establishing a context (as your rule illustrates very well).

It is, however, possible to create a context where a limited set of POJOs that may or may not have been inserted as facts can be matched by a pattern: via the `from` phrase. Here's essentially the same rule, but without Element and SubElement being facts:

```
rule "from rule"
when
  // find a container 
  $container : Container( $elements : elements )

  // where there is an element within its elements list
  $element : Element($subEl: subElement ) from $elements

  // that has a sub element
  $subElement : SubElement(this == $element.subElement, data == "DEF")
                from $subEl;
then
    System.out.println( "found Container " + $container +
                        " for " + $subElement.getData());
end
```

But, besides being visible in a general context, insertion as a fact has another consequence as well: facts can be modified with the engine being aware of that modification. In the "from rule", a modify of $subElement isn't possible, and so any modification setting that SubElement's data to "DEF" will not make this rule fire (not even if you insert the SubElement POJO).

For completeness sake: reasoning with a hierarchy of objects (composition) is also simplified by adding the references to the parent object, e.g.

```
rule "linkage rule"
when
    // a sub element GHI
    $subElement : SubElement( data == "GHI", $element: element)
then
    System.out.println( "found Container " + $element.getContainer() +
                        " for " + $subElement.getData());
end
```